# Custom plugin .so library is not found for BlackBerry 10 with Cordova 2.8

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I have developed a custom BlackBerry WebWorks Native Extension plugin to work with the new Cordova v2.8.

In order to make sure I got everything right I wrote a simple "echo" plugin like the one described in their guide found here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_plugin-development_blackberry10_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20BlackBerry%2010 (which is quite vague to be honest).

Then I wrote the fully blown implementation. The C++ project built fine and adding the plugin and deploying to the simulator was also fine without any errors. But when the plugin is invoked I get the following error "Require Error Can't find /usr/lib/webplatform/plugins/jnext/.so Library cannot be found".

I used an FTP client to browse the simulator's filesystem and indeed the .so plugin file is not at that directory BUT when I run the app with the simple plugin (which works) the plugin is still not at that directory. I can see that the plugin exists in the folder where the app is copied.

Is there a way to debug this? Any ideas..?

Answer (score 0):

The .so file must live in the /native/simulator/plugins/jnext/ folder of your app, and if so they will be copied to the correct place. Make sure that it is the simulator .so file. (This is done by plugman via the plugin.xml)

If the file is in the correct place and is the correct version and you still get the popup it is likely a missing dependency and you'll need to check your build scripts.

Comment: I believe it's a missing dependency. I assumed any dependencies would get picked up when building the project since they're included in the Includes of my extension. How would I go about solving this? Include the dependencies manually in the project?

Comment: OK. I have verified that the problem is that I am referencing some Qt headers. I assumed this would be OK as I have written a simple Cascades project to test my plugin but when I add the project as a plugin it fails to run ('giving me the misleading Require error)

Comment: I find using the momentics "Add Library" wizard tends to fix much of this, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a message saying the application can not load your .so file, it's nearly always a linking problem. Your code may build in the IDE, but not actually link on the device. Make sure you've included all your dependencies and includes properly, on the build that you have loaded. Also, make sure that you've loaded the device build on a device, and the simulator on a simulator.

From https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/BB10-Cordova/Template

I wish I knew how to rectify this. Did you have any luck?